# Problem about dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let be $X$ a normed space, $M$ a subespace of $X$ and $u\in{X}$. Prove that there exists $f\in{X^*}$ such that $f(x)\leq{dist(x,M)}$ $\forall{x\in{X}}$ and 
$f(u)=dist(u,M)$.

I think that I have to use Hahn-Banach Theorem but I don't know how to do it.

Coold someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: well f(x)=dist(x,M) satisfies this.

Comment: But, dist(x,M) is not linear, no?

Comment: Is X a vector space ?

Comment: Yes, X is a vector space

Comment: Just apply Hahn-Banach with the sublinear functional $\operatorname{dist}(\cdot, M)$. Start with a functional on the span of $u$.

Comment: Ok; so, I have to find a functional on the $span(u)$ such that $f(x)\leq{dist(x,M)} \forall{x\in{span(u)}}$?

Comment: I have tried to use this functional $f(\lambda*u)=\lambda$ but I think that  this doesn't satisfy the condition